# Setting up network connectivity between 2 VirtualBox Windows VMs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, virtualbox, local-area-network, internal-dns

I am attempting to set up a set of VMs on Virtualbox and have configured one as a DC running Windows Server 2008 R2, and it's intended to function as a primary DNS server.

I have created a reverse lookup zone of 10.10.10.x. Its adapter address is 10.10.10.10. In Virtualbox, I have left the default adapter settings for the machine alone; it defaulted to NAT.

A second image, also hosting Windows Server 2008 R2, is up on the host. It too has a default adapter type of NAT. I would like this image to use the DC as its primary DNS server. It's address is 10.10.10.20. However, when I try to set the DNS to .10 using

`Netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Local Area Connection" static 10.10.10.10 primary`

from an elevated command prompt, I get a message indicating the DNS server is incorrect or does not exist.

The host is an OSX machine and again, all images are running on the host. I suspect I have not selected the correct adapter type for one or both of them.

How can I get this machine to use the DC image as its DNS server?

Comment: Is this for dev/test or for production? If it's for production, you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @EEAA Nope, its for development. I am setting up VMs along the guidelines provided for some training I am doing. These are somewhat disposable in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about adapter type. "Nat" is creating a different network & adapter for each VM. You need to switch the VMs' adapter types to NatNetwork or Internal networking or Bridged Networking. But certainly just "Nat" is not proper type of adapter.

- Nat Networking: Both VM should use the same name "NatNetwork" is default
- Internal Networking: Both VMs' adapter should attached to same name "intnet" default.
- Bridged Networking. Both uses the same bridge interface created via OS X System preferences > Network > Manage virtual interfaces > Create new bridge

You can get info here.
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

Comment: Thanks - I chose internal networking and I was able to register the DNS entry.